# What is wrong with my Android style attributes, actionbar title hidden or no color?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, textcolor, android-titlebar

I'm trying to customize **ActionBar** using styles.xml on KITKAT and older versions.

This is as far I got it, but missing actionbar title, no color inserted properly, height or what is wrong?

**Here is my styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="style/Theme.MyApp">
    <item name="elevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">56dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon_placeholder_compat</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For change color of action bar and status bar:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
</style>
```